# Are there any undesirable effects from tagging a release in branches other than master?

Tags: git

In our team we use the `git-flow` model to manage branches in `git`, but we still do most of that management manually. We develop on **feature-branches** and merge those to **develop** branch once the feature-branches have been reviewed. When we are ready for a release, we merge **develop** to **master** and create a release tag from master.

Today someone in our team tagged for release from **develop**, not **master**.

Would that have any undesirable consequences to our release flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think it will have big affect for your git work folw, tag just provide a snapshot memeory for the current repo status.

So there is no big deal where you make the tags.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. That's what I thought at first, but wanted to confirm. I'd like to research more/hear more before I mark a reply as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

One undesired consequence may be that anyone who only pulls the master branch may not see that new release tag if that only exists in your develop branch.

```
   mkdir gittest 
   cd gittest/ 
   git init 
   touch master1 
   git add master1 
   git commit  
   git checkout -b develop 
   touch develop1 
   git add develop1 
   git commit 
   git checkout master  
   git tag masterTag 
   git checkout develop  
   git tag develTag 
   git checkout master 
   cd .. 
   git clone gittest/.git myclone 
   cd myclone/ 
   git log --oneline --decorate
```

Git log will return something like:

```
d614a96 (HEAD, tag: masterTag, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) first master commit
```

and as you can see there does not seem to be any other tag available. So for anyone who is not interested in your development branches it will seem like the `develTag` tag does not exist and will therefore probably only install your application up to `masterTag`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But tags live in their own world, don't they? I mean, they can't be merged from one branch to another afaik. If my assumption is correct, there's no detrimental effect on having tagged a release from develop instead of master? That's what I'm not sure about...

Comment: I don't know what the expected workflow of your repository is, but I have included an example of what I mean.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you're putting into this. I haven't tried your example on my own terminal, but can see that you got a point just by reading it, it makes sense. But I did a simple `$ git pull` while checked out to `master`. All the new tags were retrieved, including the one that was tagged from `develop`. My guess is that it will all depend on how one manages tags in `git`. One would have to share the tags to be able to retrieve them from remote and not have issues when cloning. The `develTag` would be missed in your example, but if not if it had been shared first.

Comment: "If you have a lot of tags that you want to push up at once, you can also use the --tags option to the git push command. This will transfer all of your tags to the remote server that are not already there."

`$ git push origin --tags`

"Now, when someone else clones or pulls from your repository, they will get all your tags as well."

[Git Basics - Tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Comment: +1 for showing that one might miss tags when they are not pushed / shared to the remote.